# Is it a bad or good useMemo to memorize and return filtred array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Recentrly I came across I youtube video about usememo

In the video the guy makes the statement: 
"useMemo works very well when you give primitive values for props, 
but it does not work so well when you give objects or arrays for props"

I'm not sure if I understood this statememt, now I'm wondering... 
Is it a good Idea or bad to use useMemo to filter and return an array? 
To me it looks like an expensive function that should be memorized but now
I'm not so sure.

I have the following custom hook:

```
import { useMemo } from "react"

export function useSearch(array: any[], search: string, field: string) {
  const filteredArray = useMemo(() =>
    array.filter(entry => {
      if (search === "") return entry
      else if (entry[field].toLocaleLowerCase()
        .includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())) return entry
    })
    , [array, search])
  return {
    filteredArray
  }
}
```

The first param takes the array I want to filter 
The second the search string I'm inputing 
and the field I wanna search by.

Is it a good Idea use useMemo to memorize this kind of function?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be bad. The dependencies are:

```js
[array, search]
```

Where `array` is a compound object value and `search` is any possible string. The number of combinations you could come up with for these two values is extremely large and therefore will memoize many values.

Beyond that, the biggest factor is that as `array` immutably changes, new `array` values are created. If the input `array` is `[1,2,3]` and then becomes `[2,3]`, if it ever goes back to `[1,2,3]`, it will not be the *same* `[1,2,3]` as the first, and therefore will not get memoized value.

The `search` is state, and `array.filter(... => /* search */)` is derived (computed) state. It is an anti-pattern to store derived state. This is what React calls [the single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned).

As alternative, you may consider using a debouncing technique so that the search only happens 150ms after the user stops typing. For a query of `hello`, your code will memoize for `[array, "h"]`, `[array, "he"]`, `[array, "hel"]`, `[array, "hell"]` and `[array, "hello"]`. The debounce technique does not use memoization but optimizes by skipping many unwanted searches.

Comment: Thank you very much I guess you're right there are too many different possible values to be memorized that for sure can be expensive.

Comment: And because there are so many unique values, it's unlikely any input will actually hit the cache and benefit from the memo. The result is a large cache with very infrequent optimization happening.